# My Seagate 2TB External hard drive is not showing and if shown in disk it shows with wrong size?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am using ubuntu 19, and my seagate external hardrive stopped showing. I also tried in other OS like windows and it is the same issue.
[HardDrive shows like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUarT.png)
It is also showing the wrong drive size

Comment: How old is it? Drives may break down.

Comment: Its like 1 and a half year @harrymc

Comment: You might be unlucky. If you can, try it in another enclosure and another computer. If it never works, then you know the answer.

Comment: 144,115 TB, sounds like an overflow condition with the partition manager, that would be 144 Exabytes (whatever is larger than Petabytes)?

Comment: yes, and it is not even showing in fdisk cmd @Ramhound

Comment: Last-ditch effort: try to salvage any data, then try removing all partitions and creating one new partition. BTW, it looks like an external USB drive, meant to run a short while and then sleep. Has it been running continuously, which would shorten its life?

Comment: Hard drive is not showing in the explorer @DrMoishePippik also not in fdisk cmd

Comment: DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/, is a free Windows tool that *might* be able to access it... or not.